# How can I convert in R this HTML to JSON?

Tags: html, json, r, web-scraping, rcurl

```
require(Rcurl)

uris = c("https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.json",
         "https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/.json")
JSON <- getURIAsynchronous(uris)
```

This gives me a table of two html files. I would like to get the JSON. Kind of like fromJSON(readLines(url, warn = F)) but asynchronous.

Comment: When I run that code (with `library(RCurl)` corrected) I get something that looks like JSON.

Comment: I can even run `RJSONIO::fromJSON(JSON)` and I get a list.